# How do i say "party1 and party2 has same amount of votes" else party1 has won the election

Tags: php, mysql

***EDIT***

ok i have fixed any errors i have had now but the only thing im struggling to understand is why i dont get the name of the parties appearing on screen now!

```
<?php 
$id = $_GET['election'];

$result = mysql_query(
    sprintf("
        SELECT votes.party, COUNT(votes.vote_id)
        FROM votes
        WHERE election_id = %d
        GROUP BY election_id, votes.party
        ORDER BY COUNT(votes.vote_id) DESC",
        mysql_real_escape_string($id)
    )
);

// change is here

$votes = false;
$winners = array();

while ( ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result) ) && ( ($votes==false) || ($row['vote_count']===$votes) ) ) {
  $winners[] = $row['party'];
  $votes = $row['vote_count'];
}
echo '<hr><h3>'.'Results</h3><hr>'.'<h4>'.implode(' and ', $winners).' won with '.$votes.'</h4>';

?>
```

all i am getting on screen is 'and won with'. i am not getting the names of the parties to appear! anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

They may be 2 winners but also 3, 4 ... who knows.

Here is the generic code that will display all the real winners:

```
// no change here

$id = $_GET['election'];

$result = mysql_query(
    sprintf("
        SELECT votes.party, COUNT(votes.vote_id) AS vote_count
        FROM votes
        WHERE election_id = %d
        GROUP BY election_id, votes.party
        ORDER BY COUNT(votes.vote_id) DESC",
        mysql_real_escape_string($id)
    )
);

// change is here

$votes = false;
$winners = array();
while ( ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) && ( ($votes==false) || ($row['vote_count']===$votes) ) ) {
  $winners[] = $row['party'];// was missing the $ before row['party'];
  $votes = $row['vote_count'];
}

echo '<hr><h3>'.'Results</h3><hr>'.'<h4>'.implode(' and ', $winners).' won with '.$votes.'</h4>';
```

Comment: it says : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' on line 82. line 82 is where you write the while statement: while ( ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result) ) && ( ($votes==false) || ($row['vote_count']===$votes) ) {

Comment: There is a missing closing `)` before the `{`

Comment: The column vote_count does not exist. You need to add an alias - `COUNT(votes.vote_id) AS vote_count`. It sounds like you are developing with error reporting turned off. Try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of your script.

Comment: I've updated the snippet: I've changed the SQL of the original question, it now has an alias on the second column : "COUNT(votes.vote_id) AS vote_count".

Comment: @Skrol29, nope still getting the 'and won with' statment without the parties name appearing on screen. when i put in error_reporting(E_ALL); i get an error which says: Notice: Undefined index: party on line 85 and 86! line 85 and 86 is: $winners[] = $row['party']; $votes = $row['vote_count'];

Comment: fixed: replace mysql_fetch_row() with mysql_fetch_assoc(). That came from your first snippet, I didn't see the mistake.